# Optimal flexible box layout algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, layout

I'm implementing the [CSS3 flexible box layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/) as defined by the W3C, which is similar to [Mozilla's box model for xul](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/The_Box_Model). While these standards specify how the model should behave, they don't give any details on how they should be implemented.

The parts of the model I'm interested in are:

1. Boxes have a width and height.
2. Boxes can contain other boxes.
3. Container boxes (parent boxes) are responsible for sizing and positioning the boxes they contain (child boxes).
4. Boxes have orientation which may be horizontal or vertical. The orientation determines how the child boxes are positioned and resized.
5. Child boxes may be flexible or inflexible. If the child box is inflexible it is drawn at the size specified in the width and height parameters. If it is flexible, then it is resized to fit into the available space in the parent container.
6. Flexibility is relative to other child boxes in the same container, boxes with higher flexibility are resized more than boxes with lower flexibility.
7. Child boxes can be constrained to a minimum or maximum size. If the child box is flexible, the parent box will never resize it below the minimum size, or above the maximum size.

Features 1-5 can be implemented quite efficiently. Feature 6 is problematic as the most efficient algorithm I can come up with is quite naive. The algorithm works as follows:

1. Place all the boxes in a list.
2. Loop through each child box and resize it using the flexibility to determine the amount to resize it by.
3. If the size exceeds one of the limits, then set the box size to the limit and remove it from the list, and start from the beginning of the list.

Step 3 is where the efficiency drops. For example, if there are ten items in the list, and the last one has a constraint, then the algorithm calculates the size for the first nine items, then when it reaches the tenth one it needs to redo all of the calculations. I have considered keeping the list sorted and first sizing all the constrained boxes, however this comes with the cost of added complexity and the overhead of sorting the list.

I expect there is a recognised optimal solution considering this is a fairly common feature in browsers and frameworks (XUL, .Net, Flex, etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most box/container layout algorithms use a 2 pass algorithm. In the case of .NET (WPF) they are called "Measure" and "Arrange". Each control can measure its content and report a "desired size" in the recursive measure pass.

During the second pass (arrange) if the childrens desired sizes will not fit inside the parent, the parent uses its layout algorithm to provide the actual size to each child, for example by assigning the actual size weighted by desired size. Minimum/maximum sizes, box flexibility etc can come into play here.

More information on the WPF layout system
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx

Xul layout
http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/xul/layout.html

Comment: +1 for the interesting links and information. I am currently doing two passes, the problem being in the arrange phase, and exactly what happens during this phase is what I'm trying to optimise.

Comment: The arrange phase should be a simple mapping from desired sizes to actual sizes, using some mapping function (layout algorithm). For example, if you want to fit two children of width 60 into a width of 100, you could end up with {50, 50} in a fair assignment, or {60, 40} in another assignment function. Are you seeing the layout as a "resize" operation rather than an operation that "assigns new sizes"? Any old size that a children has should be irrelevant during the layout pass, correct?

Comment: Correct, every layout pass is unique. The reason I can't use a straightforward mapping as you describe is due to the min/max size constraints. For example, given two children of width 40, one may be constrained to a max width of 60. When both children are being fitted into a region 200 wide, then the constrained child must be 60, and the other can expand to 140. On a normal pass it will try to assign the width of 100 to both boxes. When it encounters the constrained box, it needs to recalculate the non-constrained box. Is there not a way to do all the calculations only once?

Comment: If you want to assign two children which both are overfilled, into a region 200 wide, and the first child has a max width of 60, their desired sizes will be {60,200}. You can assign these desired sizes in many ways: "first served": {60,140}. "weight by desired": {46, 154}. The problem with "first served" is that if the order is reversed the assignment will be {200,0} which is not desireable. A compromise is to do a 2 pass arrange which starts with a fair {100,100}, then clamps to min/max sizes to achieve {60,100} and finally distributes the slack on unconstrained children for {60,140}.

Comment: Looks like I have ended up back where I started. Consider 3 boxes {20, 20, 20} which need to fit into a space of 300. Box #1 has a maximum of 110, box #3 has a maximum of 60. In the first iteration the boxes are {100, 100, 100}, then they're clamped to {100,100,60}, and the last pass re-distributes the widths to {120,120,60}. Oops, box #1 has just exceeded it's maximum! Clamping is applied again {110,100,60}, and then widths are redistributed {110,90,60}. I rolled this repetition into a loop and ended up with the same code I had before.

Comment: I think you should look to the WPF grid column width assignment algorithm for reference. http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html
First look at how the column definitions are made, and then perhaps try to look at the implementation of the measure/arrange code (I'm looking at it through a reflector such as Jetbrains DotPeek or RedGate's Reflector). First, you should ask yourself what the definitions of the sizes are. Are they "desired sizes"? or measured sizes (if they contain children themselves). The wpf columns have 3 distinct settings: fixed/auto/star that make a lot of sense I think.