# Fast layout algorithms for UI

Tags: algorithm, performance, user-interface, layout

I have a number of UI elements like panels, edit fields, buttons, labels etc. so panels contain other panels which contain input fields, editors and so on. Most of the elements are editable and/or resizable which means whenever I change anything, a lot of adjacent UI elements should change their width, height and x/y position on the pane. It works fine with a small number of elements but incredibly slow when the number of elements is thousands.
Is there a fast layout algorithm which can be used in this case? Note that I cannot use any existing layout managers and should come up with my own implementation.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried an obvious brute force approach by calculating everything whenever I edit or resize something.

Comment: I guess your "recalculate everything" algorithm is just too slow. Look at how HTML+CSS can lay out a web page with thousands of elements instantly. Recalculating everything should be (close-to) linear in the number of elements.

Comment: What technologies are you using? I thought if you can't use existing libraries you might be doing low-level drawing on an embedded platform?

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908846/optimal-flexible-box-layout-algorithm

Comment: @maniek you're right :)

Comment: @SilverRampart 's answer is exactly where I was going to go.  Don't reinvent the wheel, there are tons of libraries out there that can help with this that are highly tuned.  Bootstrap for example is easy to just slide into place.  If you were using react I would suggest using Google's Material UI components.  Their grid is very robust and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest taking a leaf out of the Android playbook and have a larger 'grid' and keep everything sized in modular multiples - this avoids you needing to solve the knapsack problem everytime!

For example, instead of having a button with an width of 80 and a height of 40 you store this as metadata as {2:1} (assuming your layout grid is 40^40 squares).

This way if you have a work panel with space of, say, {2:12} this could be filled with two objects of size {2:6} or maybe 3 of size {2:4}.

It's pretty simple to fit-to-max too as any available space can just be scaled up (say you delete a {1:1} item you can just expand the one next to it to take the space etc - you can of course create your own rules around whether objects can scale in single directions etc.

The other advantage of this approach is that you can easily manage different screen sizes and resolutions too while still keeping the same framework and look and feel.